# How can I animate margin that is added by sidemenu click which is adding class to a particular class?

Tags: jquery, css

I have a function that on click opens menu, also adds class to an existing class on the page, which is adding margin-right: 300px;, but I cannot make it animate.

I tried this bellow, but...

```
    -webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease;
    -moz-transition: all 0.5s ease;
    -o-transition: all 0.5s ease;
    transition: all 0.5s ease;
```

is not working.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
$(document).ready(function(){
$('.sidemenu-trigger').on('click', function(e){
if ($(".sidemenu-trigger").hasClass("active")) {
$('.content-grid').addClass('collapsed-menu-grid');
} else {
$('.content-grid').removeClass('collapsed-menu-grid');
}
})
});
});
```

```
.content-grid.collapsed-menu-grid {
    margin-right: 300px !important;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease;
    -moz-transition: all 0.5s ease;
    -o-transition: all 0.5s ease;
    transition: all 0.5s ease;
}
.content-grid {
    transform: none !important;
    margin: 0 auto !important;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease;
    -moz-transition: all 0.5s ease;
    -o-transition: all 0.5s ease;
    transition: all 0.5s ease;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try `toggleClass` method

```js
$('.content-grid').toggleClass("collapsed-menu-grid");
```

Comment: remove the `if` and `else` statements and replace them with the above code.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I cannot use your function.
On my website there is possibility to open particular page with already collapsed side menu, in this case, such a function will give opposite result of what it should do.
Anyway, I tested it, and still, there is no animation.